# Show the Newton method converges to 0 quadratically?

Tags: convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

Using taylor series, show that if $x_n$ converges to a root, $f(x_n)$ usually converges to 0 quadratically.

I reached a point I think I need to show that

$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x_{n+1})}{f(x)^2} = c$ for a nonzero constant c.

Am I on the right track and how do I continue? Also does the "usually" mean that sometimes it takes linear time to converge?

Comment: Looks kinda reasonable. As to the “usually” bit, you will find that convergence is slower if $f'$ vanishes at the zero of $f$. Just try it for yourself, using $f(x)=x^2$ as a test case. I think you can compute the $n$th iterate of Newton explicitly in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $f(\xi)=0$, $\>f'(\xi)\ne0$, and let $x_0$ and $x_1$ be two successive Newton approximants to  $\xi$. We can compute the value $f(\xi)$ by means of a Taylor expansion of $f$ at $x_0$: There is a point $\xi_*$ between $x_0$ and $\xi$ such that
$$0=f(\xi)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(\xi-x_0)+{f''(\xi_*)\over 2}(\xi-x_0)^2\ .$$
After dividing by $f'(x_0)$ (which we may assume $\ne0$) we obtain
$$0={f(x_0)\over f'(x_0)}-x_0+\xi+{f''(\xi_*)\over 2f'(x_0)}(x_0-\xi)^2\ .$$
Taking into account the definition of $x_1$ this can be rewritten as
$$x_1-\xi={f''(\xi_*)\over 2f'(x_0)}(x_0-\xi)^2\ .\tag{1}$$
This already shows that the approximants $x_n$ converge "quadratically" to $\xi$.

Now you are interested in the function values $f(x_n)$. By the mean value theorem there are points $\xi_i$ $\>(i=0,1$) with 
$$f(x_i)=f(x_i)-f(\xi)=f'(\xi_i)(x_i-\xi),\quad{\rm resp.,}\quad x_i-\xi={f(x_i)\over f'(\xi_i)}\ .$$
Introducing this into $(1)$ we obtain
$${f(x_1)\over f'(\xi_1)}={f''(\xi_*)\over 2f'(x_0)}\left({f(x_0)\over f'(\xi_0)}\right)^2\ ,$$
or
$$f(x_1)={f'(\xi_1) f''(\xi_*)\over 2f'(x_0)f'^2(\xi_0)}\>\bigl(f(x_0\bigr)^2\ .\tag{2}$$
Since with $x_n\to\xi$ the points $\xi_*$, $\xi_0$, $\xi_1$ converge to $\xi$ as well the content of $(2)$ is that
$$f(x_{n+1})\doteq C\bigl(f(x_n)\bigr)^2\qquad(n\gg1)\ ,$$
where $C:={\displaystyle{f''(\xi)\over 2f'^2(\xi)}}$.